# Need help centering text and overlapping with background color

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centering my home page text (the  tag). I'm not sure why it's not working.

I have a button that performs a short animation when the user hovers over the button. The button is supposed to fill with red but when I change the background color of the #main container, the button loses its animation. I'm assuming that it's getting hidden behind main's background color but I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

```css
/*CSS DOCUMENT*/
/* Notes:
Hashtags are for ID's and dots(.) are for classes

If you do #nav .selected for example, it would look for .selected within the nav ID.
*/

/*Import stuff for button animations */
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

/*Global Button Syles*/
a.animated-button:link, a.animated-button:visited {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 30px auto 0;
 padding: 14px 15px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 overflow: hidden;
 letter-spacing: .08em;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease;
 transition: all 1s ease;
}
a.animated-button:link:after, a.animated-button:visited:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 height: 0%;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 width: 150%;
 z-index: -1;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
 transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
}
a.animated-button:link:hover, a.animated-button:visited:hover {
 color: #FFF;
 text-shadow: none;
}
a.animated-button:link:hover:after, a.animated-button:visited:hover:after {
 height: 450%;
}
a.animated-button:link, a.animated-button:visited {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 30px auto 0;
 padding: 14px 15px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size:14px;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 overflow: hidden;
 letter-spacing: .08em;
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease;
 transition: all 1s ease;
}
/*End Global Button Styles*/

/*Victoria Button Style 3*/
a.animated-button.victoria-three {
 border: 2px solid #D24D57;
 color: #333;
}
a.animated-button.victoria-three:after {
 background: #D24D57;
 opacity: .5;
 -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
a.animated-button.victoria-three:hover:after {
 height: 140%;
 opacity: 1;
}


body{
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #D24D57;

}

h1{
 padding: 10px;
 align: left;
}

.light_saber{
 align:bottom;
 margin:5px;
}

h2{
 align:center;
}


#container{
 width: auto;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#header{
 background-color: #D24D57;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px;
}

#content{
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; /*top right bottom left*/
 width: auto;
}

#nav{
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #999;
}

#nav ul{
 list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #333;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

#nav .selected{
 font-weight: bold;
}

#main{
 width: auto;
 height: 2000px;
 float: center;
 background-color: #999;
}

#main .profile_picture{
 border-radius: 20px;
 width: 250px;
 height: 350px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: right;
 background-color: #333;
}

#footer{
 clear: both; /*Lets get past all the floating elements and then display footer*/
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #999;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >


<head>
    <title>Siman Shrestha</title>
    <link href = "stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="header">
   <h1>Siman Shrestha</h1>
      <div class="light_saber">
        <img src="light_saber.gif" alt="Whoops, something went wrong :-(">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div id="content">
        <div id="nav">
         <ul>
     <li><a class="selected" href=""> Home </a></li> <!--creates a class tag and hyperlink*/-->
     <li><a class="selected" href=""> About </a></li>
        <li><a class="selected" href=""> Contact </a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
     <h2>Home Page</h2>
     <img src="IMG_1689.jpg" class="profile_picture" alt="Whoops, something went wrong :-(">
        <!--Resume Button-->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="CS Resume- 10_2017.pdf" class="btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-three">Resume</a>
            </div>
            <p>
                Saucin'
            </P>
        </div>

   </div>

   <div id="footer">
    Copyright &copy; 2017 Siman Shrestha
   </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the z-index works

```css
/*CSS DOCUMENT*/
/* Notes:
Hashtags are for ID's and dots(.) are for classes

If you do #nav .selected for example, it would look for .selected within the nav ID.
*/

/*Import stuff for button animations */
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

/*Global Button Syles*/
a.animated-button:link, a.animated-button:visited {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 30px auto 0;
 padding: 14px 15px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 overflow: hidden;
 letter-spacing: .08em;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease;
 transition: all 1s ease;
}
a.animated-button:link:after, a.animated-button:visited:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 height: 0%;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 width: 150%;
 z-index: -1;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
 transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
}
a.animated-button:link:hover, a.animated-button:visited:hover {
 color: #FFF;
 text-shadow: none;
}
a.animated-button:link:hover:after, a.animated-button:visited:hover:after {
 height: 450%;
}
a.animated-button:link, a.animated-button:visited {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 30px auto 0;
 padding: 14px 15px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size:14px;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 overflow: hidden;
 letter-spacing: .08em;
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease;
 transition: all 1s ease;
}
/*End Global Button Styles*/

/*Victoria Button Style 3*/
a.animated-button.victoria-three {
 border: 2px solid #D24D57;
 color: #333;
    z-index:998;
}
a.animated-button.victoria-three span{
    z-index:999;
}

a.animated-button.victoria-three:after {
 background: #D24D57;
 opacity: .5;
 -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
a.animated-button.victoria-three:hover:after {
 height: 140%;
 opacity: 1;
}


body{
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #D24D57;

}

h1{
 padding: 10px;
 align: left;
}

.light_saber{
 align:bottom;
 margin:5px;
}

h2{
 align:center;
}


#container{
 width: auto;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#header{
 background-color: #D24D57;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px;
}

#content{
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; /*top right bottom left*/
 width: auto;
}

#nav{
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #999;
}

#nav ul{
 list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #333;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

#nav .selected{
 font-weight: bold;
}

#main{
 width: auto;
 height: 2000px;
 float: center;
 background-color: #999;
}

#main .profile_picture{
 border-radius: 20px;
 width: 250px;
 height: 350px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: right;
 background-color: #333;
}

#footer{
 clear: both; /*Lets get past all the floating elements and then display footer*/
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #999;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >


<head>
    <title>Siman Shrestha</title>
    <link href = "stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="header">
   <h1>Siman Shrestha</h1>
      <div class="light_saber">
        <img src="light_saber.gif" alt="Whoops, something went wrong :-(">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div id="content">
        <div id="nav">
         <ul>
     <li><a class="selected" href=""> Home </a></li> <!--creates a class tag and hyperlink*/-->
     <li><a class="selected" href=""> About </a></li>
        <li><a class="selected" href=""> Contact </a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
     <h2>Home Page</h2>
     <img src="IMG_1689.jpg" class="profile_picture" alt="Whoops, something went wrong :-(">
        <!--Resume Button-->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="CS Resume- 10_2017.pdf" class="btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-three"><span>Resume</span></a>
            </div>
            <p>
                Saucin'
            </P>
        </div>

   </div>

   <div id="footer">
    Copyright &copy; 2017 Siman Shrestha
   </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I change the z-index, the animation does work but It covers the text inside the button. I tried changing the z-index for the #main container but that didn't do anything.

Comment: I added a span to my answer, the span has the index of 999 and the button has the index of 998. Does that fix it?